# Replace text is not working in c# which is read from .chtml file

Tags: c#

```
string resumeTemplate = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Html\Html\Views\Home\ResumeTemplate.cshtml"); // saple screen path
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                com.Connection = con;
                com.CommandText = "SP_RESUMEGET";
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@USER_ID", userID));
                SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                ada.Fill(dataTable);


            }
            string firstName = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[0]["FIRST_NAME"]);

            resumeTemplate.Replace("{{FirstName}}", firstName);
```

Here i'm reading the content from cshtml page where html content is there with placeholders and i want to replace that.

But it is not replacing.

Where I did the mistake?

**Contents of ResumeTemplate.cshtml**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>{{FirstName}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What are the contents of ResumeTemplate.cshtml file ?

Comment: apart from answer com.Connection = con; line seemed redundant to me

Answer (score 3):

`String.Replace()` returns a new string, rather than acting on the object it's called from, so you need to assign the result of the method to the string, like so:

```
resumeTemplate = resumeTemplate.Replace("{{FirstName}}", firstName);
```

More information can be found in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the file. String.Replace returns a new String. (Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8)

You need to apply the return value of Replace to a string. Something like

```
resumeTemplate = resumeTemplate.Replace("{{FirstName}}", firstName);
```